# grouped tableview in iOS6 not reflecting in older iOS versions

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, ipad

I have started using Xcode 4.5 for a new iPad (split view) project , I have a MasterViewController which is a subclass of UITableViewController.
I have made the tableView in xib of this MasterViewController to be Grouped style.

This works perfectly in iOS 6.0, but for iOS 4.3/iOS 5.0, the table is being shown as a plain table, and even the background of the table is not being set.
Please help!